# In Blazor WASM, how I can set a value from an API as a Singleton value on startup?

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly

So I've been playing with Blazor and I have the following:

1. I've created a Singleton Service that set's a value for the version of the program that I can access in the rest of the software
2. I've created a web service call to get data from a separate API which can be used to populate on a razor page.

However, I've been trying to figure out how to set something on startup of the app that can check an API for a value and set a variable to that value that can be used for the life of the app running.

I figured I could create a Singleton service that calls the API but I'm having a difficult time figuring that out. The value I want to store is simple, just a string.

Answer (score 0):

In **program.cs:**

```
var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISomeService, SomeService>();
```

Where `ISomeService` is an interface, and `SomeService` is a class that implements your interface.  It contains the functionality that gets your data from the desired API.

In your razor page code:

```
[Inject] ISomeService MyService { get; set; }
```

To retrieve the data:

```
string value = MyService.GetValue();
```

Which is a method you have defined in `ISomeService.cs` and implemented in `Service.cs`.

Comment: Thanks @Robert Harvey, I did try that but I ended up getting the following error "Cannot consume scoped service 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient' from singleton"

Comment: [This article explains why](https://codingblast.com/asp-net-core-dependency-injection-cannot-consume-scoped-service/).

Comment: In WASM, AddSingleton and AddScoped has the same outcome.  See https://chrissainty.com/service-lifetimes-in-blazor/.  Register your ISomeService as Scoped and you should be OK to consume HttpClient.